# Can you use the html5 voice capture input on a mobile browser (without webkit)?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i do that?

An html 5 page that allowed users to record voice and send the audio file to my web server

Answer (score 3):

This isn't yet possible using pure JavaScript. [Chrome has a speech-to-text API](http://www.web2voice.com/chrome-speech-input.html), but you'll have to use Flash to do this in a cross-browser way.

**Edit**: Found the Chrome tag:

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech />
```

I believe there are some discussions around opening up mics and videocams to a JavaScript API but certain issues, such as security of such an API, haven't yet been worked out.